# How to extract data from the following html?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

The Html from where i want to extract data is:

```
  <div class="infoMessageInner">
    <p>
      <span ng-bind-html="servicesCtrl.texts.addressInfo" class="ng-binding">
        Fiber är beställd till adressen. Tjänsterna kan du beställa när installationen är färdig.
      </span>
      <span ng-show="servicesCtrl.address.status === 'Orderable'" class="ng-hide">
        <a ng-click="servicesCtrl.preScrollToVerticalPosition('checkout', 'checkout', '/checkoutFiber', undefined, 'Checkout fiber')">Till&nbsp;fiberbeställningen
        </a>
      </span>
      <span ng-show="servicesCtrl.address.status === 'Inquireable'" class="ng-hide">
        <a ng-click="servicesCtrl.preScrollToVerticalPosition('checkout', 'checkout', '/inquiry', undefined, 'Inquiry')">Till&nbsp;intresseanmälan</a>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
```

**I want to extract data just from the 1st span only.So far i already did post and get the solution but again problem persist i'm getting empty list of selenium web elements. **

**Code snippet is:(using Python-Selenium)**

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.infoMessageInner > p')
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.infoMessageInner > p')))
data = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.infoMessageInner > p')
```

please help and sorry for posting such question because i'm learning selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the text **Fiber är beställd till adressen. Tjänsterna kan du beställa när installationen är färdig.** just from the 1st span only you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *text to be present in the element* and you can use the following solution:

- Imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Line of code:

  ```
  #Option 1 - text_to_be_present_in_element and CSS_SELECTOR
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.infoMessageInner>p>span.ng-binding"), "Fiber är beställd till adressen"))
  #Option 2 - text_to_be_present_in_element_value and CSS_SELECTOR
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.infoMessageInner>p>span.ng-binding"), "Fiber är beställd till adressen"))
  #Option 3 - text_to_be_present_in_element and XPATH
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='infoMessageInner']/p/span[@class='ng-binding']"), "Fiber är beställd till adressen"))
  #Option 4 - text_to_be_present_in_element_value and XPATH
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='infoMessageInner']/p/span[@class='ng-binding']"), "Fiber är beställd till adressen"))
  ```
- Text will be:

  ```
  Fiber är beställd till adressen. Tjänsterna kan du beställa när installationen är färdig.
  ```

Comment: IDE is marking as error to: ''expected_condition'' .why?

Comment: from previous imports its working now but sometime gives empty result...though text is available  in the span. and thanks for helping 2nd time.

Comment: i used your suggested previous code's css selector(that you've posted) in my code and it started working.

Comment: sir its giving time out exception

Answer (score 0):

If you have no more `<span>` elements in html, you can just find first span element with `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('span').text`

Comment: Oh..but there are other different spans are present

Comment: so you can find all span in div with "infoMessageInner" class: `driver.find_element_by_class_name('infoMessageInner').find_element_by_tag_name('span').text`

Comment: Yeah this is something new to me let me try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below bindings in CSS selector

```
.ng-binding
```

Edit:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.ng-binding').text
```

Comment: have you used .text after this css selector ?

Comment: yes sir i tried and i think it was saying time out because didn't find an element time out exception occurs