# TypeError: find_element() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 5 were given

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

Attempting to open the login page and log in, at which point the link ending in `server_id=...` will be available, which is a panel to edit my server listing, where I then want to click the Update button at the bottom. Am I using `By` properly?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/bin/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://minecraft-server-list.com/login/login.php')

WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(
    expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element(
        By.NAME, 'username') or
    expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element(
        By.CLASS_NAME, 'column-heading'))

if expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element(
        By.NAME, 'username'):

    user = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
    pw = driver.find_element_by_name('password')

    user.clear()
    user.send_keys('redacted')
    pw.clear()
    pw.send_keys('redacted')

    driver.find_element_by_name('Submit').click()

    WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(
        expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element(
            By.CLASS_NAME, 'column-heading'))

    driver.get('https://minecraft-server-list.com/login/edit_server.php?server_id=redacted')

    WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(
        expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element(
            By.CLASS_NAME, 'serverdatadiv1'))

    driver.find_element_by_name('button').click()

    driver.quit()

elif expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element(
        By.CLASS_NAME, 'column-heading'):
    driver.get('https://minecraft-server-list.com/login/edit_server.php?server_id=redacted')

    WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(
        expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element(
            By.CLASS_NAME, 'serverdatadiv1'))

    driver.find_element_by_name('button').click()

    driver.quit()

driver.quit()
```

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/veggie/Desktop/devshit/projects/mcslUpdater/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    By.CLASS_NAME, 'column-heading'))
  File "C:\Users\veggie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "C:\Users\veggie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 209, in __call__
    element_text = _find_element(driver, self.locator).text
  File "C:\Users\veggie\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 411, in _find_element
    return driver.find_element(*by)
TypeError: find_element() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a typo within the [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336).

According to the definition, [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/80adb709873815b88bb57494a6908f8b86285766/py/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py#L276) should be called within a `tuple` as it is not a *function* but a *class*, where the initializer expects just **1** argument beyond the *implicit* **self**:

```
class element_to_be_clickable(object):
    """ An Expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it."""
    def __init__(self, locator):
        self.locator = locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
        element = visibility_of_element_located(self.locator)(driver)
        if element and element.is_enabled():
            return element
        else:
            return False
```

So, effectively instead of:

```
elif expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element(
    By.CLASS_NAME, 'column-heading'):
```

You need to:

```
elif WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until((expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element(
    By.CLASS_NAME, 'column-heading'))):
```

Likewise, you have to change the other instances of [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451).

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion in:

- [**init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given using WebDriverWait and expected_conditions as element_to_be_clickable with Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57903422/init-takes-2-positional-arguments-but-3-were-given-using-webdriverwait-and/57903495#57903495)
- [How to extract data from the following html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50906710/how-to-extract-data-from-the-following-html/50906829#50906829)