# Selenium webdriverwait (.text_to_be_present _in_element doesnt) seem to work and I can't find any solution to this

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

this below is the FULL html element I grabbed from the web

```
<div data-v-a27cb890="" class="text-2xl font-bold font-numeric">19.60</div>
```

as you notice, I am selecting a 20 second countdown html timer code,
The problem here is the code I wrote below doesn't seem to work. As the timer hits 15.28 seconds. I want to print it out.

```
timer = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page-scroll"]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]'), "15.28")
print(float(timer.text))
```

after WebDriverWaiting for 30 seconds it cant find the text I wanted to print out even the timer rolls past on my screen. Then it gives an TimeoutException error.

Answer (score 1):

According to [selenium.webdriver.support.wait](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html) doc, the default poll interval is 0.5s. So it might not match your expectation that can catch 15.28s. Try to customize your own interval:

```
WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
webDriverWait.pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(50)); // 50 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition, [`text_to_be_present_in_element()`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/80adb709873815b88bb57494a6908f8b86285766/py/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py#L197) should be called within a `tuple` as it is not a *function* but a *class*, where the initializer expects just **1** argument beyond the *implicit* **self**:

```
class text_to_be_present_in_element(object):
    """ An expectation for checking if the given text is present in the
    specified element.
    locator, text
    """
    def __init__(self, locator, text_):
    self.locator = locator
    self.text = text_

    def __call__(self, driver):
    try:
        element_text = _find_element(driver, self.locator).text
        return self.text in element_text
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        return False
```

So instead of:

```
timer = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page-scroll"]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]'), "15.28")
```

You need to  (add an extra parentheses):

```
timer = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page-scroll"]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]'), "15.28"))
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to extract data from the following html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50906710/how-to-extract-data-from-the-following-html/50906829#50906829)
- [**init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given using WebDriverWait and expected_conditions as element_to_be_clickable with Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57903422/init-takes-2-positional-arguments-but-3-were-given-using-webdriverwait-and/57903495#57903495)